# Why is my copy of a struct getting changed?

Tags: c

```
void sched(struct process ** process, int arrSize){
 struct process ** copy = process;
 quickSort(copy, 0, arrSize-1);
```

I have a original struct array processes which holds the original data. I want to hold that original data so I make a copy of it. I sort the copied struct and when I print the original one, it prints out the sorted struct. I could just resort everything but I am not sure why it is doing this.

Comment: You don't copy the struct. You copy the pointer of a pointer to the struct.

Comment: Write down your home address on a piece of paper, and call this `a`. Copy that piece of paper and call the copy `b`. Burn the house down whose address is on paper `b`. Now fetch paper `a` and go to that address. Is it burned down or not?

Comment: okay I see, but then how would I make a new house that looks exactly like house a? @usr2564301

Comment: (Re deleted comment). You can only copy a single `struct` by equating with `=`. For an array you can use `memcpy` (having allocated sufficient memory) and the function needs to return its address.

Comment: @usr2564301 YMMD, sometimes you have to take a lot in life. I just imagine about it with horror.

Comment: This requires a deep understanding of what you're copying or it can't be done. Many C APIs have some kind of "copy" function expressly for this purpose, but if there isn't one then you need to make one. If you make a mistake you may create a "shallow copy" and parts of it are shared with the original, leading later to all kinds of errors if one's freed and the other isn't.

Comment: @tadman thanks, made my own copy and it worked

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy each member of the struct individually in a for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++)
{
    copy[i].member1 = process[i].member1;
    copy[i].member2 = process[i].member2;
    // and so on
}
```